# Chart js legend issue in asp.net(aspx page)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, charts

I created doughnut chart using chart.js in asp.net(aspx page). But whenever i try to write legend like :  tooltipTemplate: "<%= value %>" then it shows me error `"The name 'value' does not exist in the current context."` Any suggestion?

Comment: can you show where you declare `value`

Comment: actually value is declare in chart.js file and it perfectly working in html file

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar do you understood what i said?

Comment: Provide Code Snippet For better Understanding

Comment: I assign"<%= value %> in one server variable on .cs page and fetch it from javascript on .aspx page. And it works.